# Pixelwise weighted binary cross entropy?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am writing a custom loss function in tensorflow to calulate the pixelwise weighted binary cross entropy, for a segmentation network.

I am using TensorFlow 2.12.0, numpy 1.22.3 and keras as my backend.

Here is my code:

```py
class pixelwise_weighted_binary_crossentropy(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, epsilon=1e-7, name="weighted_cross_entropy", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.epsilon =epsilon

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        
        y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, self.epsilon, 1 - self.epsilon)
        
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
        weight_mask = tf.ones(SHAPE)
        
        if (len(tf.unique(tf.reshape(y_true,[-1]))) >1):
            tmp = tf.reshape(y_true,[-1])
            _,_,[count_0,count_1] = tf.unique_with_counts(tf.constant(tmp))
            weights_0 = 0.5/(count_0.numpy()/(SHAPE[0]*SHAPE[1]))
            weights_1 = 0.5/(count_1.numpy()/(SHAPE[0]*SHAPE[1]))
            weight_mask = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true, 1), weights_1, weights_0)            
        
        loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_true * weight_mask * tf.log(y_pred))
        return loss

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'epsilon': self.epsilon,
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config, **config}
```

I get the following error:

```py
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    File "/home/apadaki/.conda/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_44703/3863106092.py", line 14, in pixelwise_weighted_binary_crossentropy_fun  *
        _,_,[count_0,count_1] = tf.unique_with_counts(tmp)

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

What am I missing here?